# IMobileServiceSyncTable PullAsync doesn't return

Tags: windows-phone-8, azure-mobile-services

I currently use Azure Mobile Services with Offline Sync and I it has been working fine. However I now have come to a problem I can't seem to debug. On the PullAsync it never returns, never goes to the Web API, it never errors, it just seems to be stuck somewhere and I don't know where.

```
IMobileServiceSyncTable<ResponseType> responseTypeTable = MobileService.GetSyncTable<ResponseType>();

await responseTypeTable.PullAsync(responseTypeTable.Where(c => c.CompanyId == companyId));
```

I use identical code elsewhere with a different type and it works well.

The only thing that happens is the Windows Phone emulator UI locks up, I can press buttons on the keyboard but the input or buttons are all frozen.

I get this on the Debug Output

> The thread 0xb80 has exited with code 259 (0x103).

After a 5 seconds and that's about it. Breakpoints everywhere, nothing happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method was in a Command (I'm using MVVMLight). When I call the function on the class initialization and just hold the value it works fine. There is obviously some bug that occurs when calling PullAsync on an event, in an async RelayCommand but getting the call out of there solves the issue.

I'll leave it at that unless anyone comes back with why it is actually happening. This is just a workaround at the moment.

Comment: Can you call other async methods in the Command?  Maybe it's a threading issue?